# How do I get a subset of a subset of records elegantly with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table `MyTable` with the following 5 columns

```
Key     OID        Date1       Date2   Val
  0       A   2020-01-01  2020-02-10     3  
  1       A   2020-01-01  2020-02-09     6  
  2       A   2020-01-02  2020-02-09     4  
  3       A   2020-01-03  2020-02-04     3  
  3       A   2020-01-03  2020-02-02     1  
  4       B   2020-01-02  2020-02-01     3  
  5       B   2020-01-03  2020-02-01     3  
  6       B   2020-01-03  2020-02-01     3  
  7       B   2020-01-04  2020-02-05     9  
  8       B   2020-01-04  2020-02-08     6  
  9       B   2020-01-04  2020-02-07     2
```

For each unique value in the `OID` column I want to

1. extract the subset of records corresponding to this OID value
2. then extract the subset of those records having the maximum date in Date1
3. then extract the unique record having the (guaranteed) maximum date in Date2

For the example above this would result in

So the result would be

```
Key     OID        Date1       Date2    Val
  3       A   2020-01-03  2020-02-04      3  
  8       B   2020-01-04  2020-02-08      6
```

I am new to SQL and struggling to think of an elegant solution.  In the spirit of having a go before posting on SO here is my attempt.  It is ugly.  I am certain it could be more succinct and idiomatic.  I just don't have the skill at this time.

```
WITH max_date1 (OID, Date1) AS
(
    SELECT OID, MAX(Date1)
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY OID
),
max_date2 (OID, Date2) AS
(
    SELECT max_date1.OID, MAX(MyTable.Date2)
    FROM max_date1 
    LEFT JOIN MyTable
    ON t2.OID = max_date1.OID
    WHERE max_date1.Date1 = MyTable.Date1
    GROUP BY max_date1.OID
).
max_dates (OID, Date1, Date2) AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM max_date1
    LEFT JOIN max_date2
    USING (OID)
)
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
LEFT JOIN max_dates
ON (
    MyTable.OID = max_dates.OID
    AND MyTable.Date1 = max_dates.Date1
    AND MyTable.Date2 = max_dates.Date2
)
```

Any improvements would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: "sql" is just a standard, you should specify which database you actually need the answer for because each implementation of "sql" varies. (add the database as a tag) tip: Often even knowing the db isn't enough so its wise to also mention which version you use.

Comment: @Tomalak whoops, you are correct, not intentional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
select * 
from (
  select *, row_number() 
    over(partition by oid order by date1 desc, date2 desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
 k  OID  Date1       Date2       Val  rn 
 -- ---- ----------- ----------- ---- -- 
 3  A    2020-01-03  2020-02-04  3    1  
 8  B    2020-01-04  2020-02-08  6    1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=373db631a3771b8a29be6d3394a071c2).

Comment: @Tomalak Maybe I'm reading wrong here. I think the query I wrote would provide that answer. Maybe I'm wrong. Will need to test.

Comment: @TheImpaler I think I need `order by date1 desc, date2 desc`?  It seems to make sense when I do that.

Comment: @Tomalak. Your comment was correct. Fixed.

Comment: @Riley Your comment was correct. Fixed.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use window functions as follows:

```
SELECT KEY
    , OID
    , Date1
    , Date2
    , Val
FROM (
    SELECT KEY
        , OID
        , Date1
        , Date2
        , Val
        , max(Date1) OVER (PARTITION BY oid) AS max_date1
        , max(Date2) OVER (PARTITION BY oid, date1) AS max_date2
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY oid, date1 order by date2 DESC) AS rn
    FROM mytable
    ) AS d
WHERE date1 = max_date1
    AND date2 = max_date2
    AND rn = 1
```

The date comparisons should locate the subset within subset, and row_number() is used to ensure just one row from each is returned.

If you prefer to use CTE's then just re-arrange the derived table into a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT KEY
        , OID
        , Date1
        , Date2
        , Val
        , max(Date1) OVER (PARTITION BY oid) AS max_date1
        , max(Date2) OVER (PARTITION BY oid, date1) AS max_date2
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY oid, date1 order by date2 DESC) AS rn
    FROM mytable
    ) 
SELECT KEY
    , OID
    , Date1
    , Date2
    , Val
FROM CTE
WHERE date1 = max_date1
    AND date2 = max_date2
    AND rn = 1
```